# How do I parse a string with brackets into array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, string-parsing

I am receiving a string with brackets already in it and need to parse it out to an array of arrays. Also, there are no commas in between elements.

I am receiving something similar to:

```
[[[a] b] c [d]]
```

and need to transform it to:

```
[[['a'], 'b'], 'c', ['d']
```

I've tried replacing all brackets with the bracket and a quote mark but that doesn't work. Ex: `[[a] b]` becomes `['['a'] b]`

I've tried JSON.parse but I need help doing a couple things before that works

1. I need to add commas in all the right places
2. I need the values inside brackets to be wrapped in quotations.

Comment: Would it be possible for that data source to *provide JSON instead*? If possible, it would be easier than having to write your own custom parser.

Comment: Please include any code attempts you've written to solve this on your own. Also, you'll need to provide the boundaries of the expected input. Will the items always just be single letters?

Comment: @Joseph I wish! This has been a real pain to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regular expression to put quotes around any sequence that doesn't include space or square brackets, and replace all spaces with comma. Then parse it as JSON.

```js
let str = '[[[a] b] c [d]]';
let json = str.replace(/[^ \[\]]+/g, '"$&"').replace(/ +/g, ',');
console.log(json);
let arr = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This was the suggestion I had in mind as well, but it won't work if the items in the array contain spaces. Though, in such a case I'm not sure what really *could* be done.

Comment: if there were spaces couldn't we just go in and remove the spaces first then execute normally? @TylerRoper

Comment: Unless there's some escaping syntax, that's not possible, since spaces are the separator.

Comment: If there are more details to the problem, put them in the question, not comments.

Comment: @barmar this is very helpful. Thank you very much!